# Can't use em dash in ghostscript command on Debian

Tags: php, bash, debian, ghostscript, eol

I have been searching for quite a bit, and can't seem to find a solution.

I have a ghostscript command in a PHP (7.4) Drupal specific script (not written by me), which seems to work fine. The command is specifically what is below:

```bash
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=converted.pdf 'path/to/filename/with and em–dash.pdf'
```

This command works fine for me on other special characters, such as æ, ø, å, but as soon as an em dash is added, it fails:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.23: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
head: cannot open '' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I have tried encasing the file path with double and single quotes, which does not seem to work. The file path is dynamically added.

I am pretty certain this is a command line issue over a PHP issue, but please do correct me if I am wrong, and I will share what I can from the script. I would very much like to avoid changing the file name, as I am certain the client will upload another file with an em dash in its name.

Couple of notes:

- I am aware PHP 7.4 is EOL and should be changed to at least 8.1 (at the time of writing)
- This is on a Debian 9 which is also EOL and should be upgraded to at least Debian 10 (at the time of writing)
- This is in connection with a Drupal 7 installation which is nearing EOL, and should also be updated to at least 9 (at the time of writing)
- Even with the information about the impending doom of outdated software, I cannot do anything about it, as I am not in charge of this stuff. So suggestions to update might be the right path to go, I unfortunately am unable to, not due to lack of skill, but to lack of "other stuff" further above in the ladder.
- The locale is en_DK.UTF-8
- GhostScript is on version 9.23

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You are using a very elderly version of Ghostscript (9.23). That's 5 years old now. Try upgrading to a recent version and then if it doesn't work you can open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com. If you can't do that then I suspect you're going to be out of luck.

Comment: Hard to say what might be off in your code when you haven't posted any of it. Best I could guess is that there's an encoding mismatch somewhere between your app and the filesystem, and that filename isn't what you think it is.